# Is that true that A is decidable if A$\le_m$A complement?

Tags: formal-languages

A is decidable if A$\le_m$A complement

Can i think that it is true because decidable is close under complement, so if A complement is decidable, so is A

Comment: that question states that A is undecidable, but this one is decidable, does the answer is the same?

Comment: You are asking whether $A \le_m$ co-$A$ implies that $A$ is decidable. That answer shows that there is some $A$ such that $A \le_m$ co-$A$ and $A$ is undecidable, proving that the implication is false.

Answer (score 0):

If co-$A$ is decidable then so is $A$, as you mention in your question.

However the mere fact that $A \le_m$ co-$A$ does not imply the dependability of $A$. See [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126136/is-there-possible-that-undecidable-language-a-where-a-is-mapping-reducible-to-a/126140#126140).